# Spring-Boot - Acessando o JpaRepository fora do escopo do Controller

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

Olá,
  Tenho uma aplicação web baseada no SpringBoot, mas que também trata um protocolo específico e para isso eu inicio um ServerSocket que aguarda conexões e as trata adequadamento.
  Abaixo um exemplo de como estou fazendo isso:

```
  public class MyServer extends Thread {
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepo;

    public MyServer() {
      start();
    }

    public run() {
     ServerSocket server = new ServerSockey(7000);
     while (true) {
       Socket sock = server.accept();
       ...
       // Handle connection here
       myRepo.findById(1);
       ...
      }
  }
}
```

O Repositorio é declarado abaixo:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyModel, Long> {
}
```

E minha classe principal, que inicia tudo:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude= {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"myComponentPackages"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= {"myRepositoriesPackages"})
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
            new MyServer();

            SpringApplication springApp = new SpringApplication(Main.class);
            springApp.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
            springApp.run(args);
        }
}
```

Claro que eu tenho muito mais, por ex, controllers, repositorios, etc, mas serve de exemplo do que estou precisando.
No caso, eu preciso acessar a instância do MyRepository no MyServer,mas como ele não está dentro do escopo de um Controller, que é chamado quando algum request é feito ao servidor web, a anotação @Autowired não funciona e a variavel myRepo está sempre como null.
A pergunta é: Como acessar este repositorio fora do contexto de uma chamanda rest, por ex?

Alguma dica ?

Obrigado,
Leandro

Comment: Utilize `@Configurable` em sua classe `MyServer`

Comment: Obrigado. mas não funcionou. Continua como null a referência para o meu repositório.
Ja tentei com @Service tbem, mas nao vai.
Me parece que ele só funciona qdo ocorre uma chamada aos meus serviços Rest via Controller.
Mas deve ter um jeito de obter acesso ao engine de injeção de dependência, pq ele está rodando, afinal de contas.

Answer (score 1):

apenas para deixar uma resposta aos proximos que vierem, a solução está neste link:
https://dzone.com/articles/autowiring-spring-beans-into-classes-not-managed-by-spring

Fiz e funcionou bem, onde eu preciso de uma instancia do MyRepository, eu faço:

MyRepository myRepo = UtilBean.getBean(MyRepository.class);

Abraços.